# Python SQLAlchemy Multiple Queries

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm not sure about the best way to approach this. Say I've got a "widget" table with fields 'id, 'name', 'size', 'color', with 10,000 rows.

When I load a webpage I will often need to look up hundreds of widgets (by id) and return one or more of the associated fields.

Once I have a database session established, is best practice to do something like:

```
thiswidget = session.query(Widget).filter(Widget.id=X)
```

Each time I need a piece of data, or should I grab all the data up front once, say like this:

```
widgetsdict = {}
for widget in session.query(Widget):
    widgets[widget.id] = (widget.name, widget.size, widget.color)
```

Then each time I need to look something up, just do:

```
thiswidget = widgetsdict[X]
```

The first method is far simpler, but is it a good idea to keep asking the database over and over?

Comment: Because this will depend on the data and its nature, it is best just profile it for your specific workload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should employ caching to prevent hitting the database too many times.

Redis or memcached are typically used for this purpose. They both act as processes which run on the client machine which can be called to save and retrieve data. You will need to set up the local server and the relevant python library.

The code you write in python should do the following:

- Checks the cache for a key
- If `None` returned, query db
- Store result in cache, set reasonable expiry

**Caching Software**

[redis](https://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

[memcached](http://memcached.org)